# Installing Java on docker in docker image

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I want to install the openjdk on the docker in docker image. When I try this is get this error message:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  openjdk8-8.121.13-r0:
    breaks: world[openjdk8=8.111.14-r0]
The command '/bin/sh -c set -x  && apk add --no-cache       openjdk8="$JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION" && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Dockerfile currently looks like this:

```
FROM docker:latest
RUN apk update
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
RUN { \
        echo '#!/bin/sh'; \
        echo 'set -e'; \
        echo; \
        echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; \
    } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u111
ENV JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION 8.111.14-r0
RUN set -x \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        openjdk8="$JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION" \
&& [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]
```

Comment: Has zero to do with docker.  This is an alpine contraint.   Remove the version and it works fine.

Comment: It also directly tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Dockerfile reference on how official Java image is baking  on top of alpine image:
https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/9a0822673dffd3e5ba66f18a8547aa60faed6d08/8-jdk/alpine/Dockerfile

Or you could do it another way around,

```
# build ontop of official Java image
FROM java:openjdk-8-jdk-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add docker
...
```

Comment: If i need to use another base image?

Comment: Then probably you would have to bake the image from your specific base image with java installation. But in most cases if the base image requires Java, they are most likely already baking their image that contain Java.

Answer (score 0):

Well as @user2105103 mentioned this is a problem with JDK version.

You could simply skip the version and problem will disappear. Example:

```
FROM docker:latest

# Default to UTF-8 file.encoding
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# add a simple script that can auto-detect the appropriate JAVA_HOME value
# based on whether the JDK or only the JRE is installed
RUN { \
        echo '#!/bin/sh'; \
        echo 'set -e'; \
        echo; \
        echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; \
    } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin

ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u111
ENV JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION 8.111.14-r0

RUN set -x && apk add --no-cache openjdk8 && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]
```

In this case you will get the latest JDK version. Hope it helps.